# Kendo Upload not showing successful in Play 2.2.2

Tags: kendo-ui, playframework-2.0, kendo-upload

I have a Kendo file upload call, here is the function:

```
  $("#fileUpload").kendoUpload({
    async: {
        saveUrl: "/people",
        autoUpload: true
    },
    multiple: false,
    complete: onComplete
});

function onComplete(e) {
    // The upload is now idle
    dataSourcePerson.read();
}
```

This calls the play routes file which triggers this method in my controller:

```
  public static Result create() {
     // Do some stuff
     return ok("Successfully loaded new users");
  }
```

My problem is that the upload box shows failure and a retry option even though the upload was a success. What should my create() method return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I needed to respond with:

```
  return ok("{\"status\":0}");
```